# my Azure changes are not getting published onto my website

Tags: git, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am following microsoft documentation to deploy my app on azure with a sql Database
I made a slight change in my connection string in appsettings.Json 
 and  did a git add .
then git commit. I then did git push azure master. **However when I navigate to my website the change is not reflected**. 
I have made changes before and they were reflected immediately.

Comment: Do you know that you can change application settings like the connection string within the azure portal?

Comment: @MartinBrandl No I did not know.

Comment: @martin BrandI Its nice to know but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure. Sorry, no clue why the changes are not reflected

Comment: Is is becasue of a case issue, where you would have both a `appsettings.Json` and a `appsettings.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you could use the Kudu tool (https://{yoursiteName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/) to check whether the appsetting.json are changed. But if you have added the connectionstring in the Azure appsetting. Azure Web Sites will automatically update the connection string **at runtime** using the **value shown in the Azure portal**. For more detail information, please refer to [Application Strings and Connection Strings Work](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/).